# Script error in site debugging source

Tags: javascript

Sanitizing site's HTML and JavaScript, I've got these errors in the console:

```
uwVEY_VSQQU:1 GET chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
?device=browser:1 GET chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
?device=browser:1 GET chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
?device=browser:1 GET chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

The link doesn't lead to a valid page and can't find any file on google with the names.

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser extensions, there is telling you that you have some extension installed that is causing the problem. It is not related with the site